# Cannot use filter pattern for largefiles extension for hg

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

My hgrc config files is as follow:

> [extensions] largefiles =
>
> [largefiles] patterns = *.jpg *.png *.bmp *.gif *.mp3 *.a *.jar *.psd
>   *.ai *.unity *.ttf *.zip *.rar

I tested by created a file `a.jpg` ,hg add `--large a.jpg`, file has been created in `.hglf` correctly. I created `b.jpg`,hg add `b.jpg`, file has been created in `.hglf` correctly as well.

> If I do not hg add --large a.jpg first, this will be failed for some
>   reason.

**Next, I created subdirectory, created c.jpg file in there,hg add c.jpg, nothing created in .hglf.** This make the filter pattern not work anymore after it's in subdirectory. What should I do to be able to "hg add *" for all file in repo and it filter correctly for which one is text file, which one is binary file as config in .hgrc config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, you have to re-read `hg help patterns`

> ```
>   *.c            any name ending in ".c" in the current directory
>   **.c           any name ending in ".c" in any subdirectory of the
>                  current directory including itself.
> ```

and fix your patterns